# Swagger Error with version upgrading version > 2.6.1 - NoSuchMethodException: BasePathAwareServicesProvider.<init>()

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have upgraded springfox to version 2.7.0(and 2.9.2):

```
<springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
<spring-boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and trying to start the application I get the next error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
>   defined in URL
>   [jar:file:.....jar!/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 1 of type [java.util.List]: Error creating bean with name
>   'basePathAwareServicesProvider' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/..............!/lib/springfox-data-rest-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/data/rest/BasePathAwareServicesProvider.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.BasePathAwareServicesProvider]:
>   No default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.BasePathAwareServicesProvider.();
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'basePathAwareServicesProvider' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:............!/lib/springfox-data-rest-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/data/rest/BasePathAwareServicesProvider.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.BasePathAwareServicesProvider]:
>   No default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.
>   **BasePathAwareServicesProvider. init ()**

**No default constructor found; BasePathAwareServicesProvider. init ()**

I have annotated the classes like this in order to avoid some errors with swaggers-ui.html:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("swaggerEnabled")
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
```

The Springboot application:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = {
        ......class,})
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"....."})
public class PlatformApiApplication {
```

I've tried some solutions from github but nothing works. Can somebody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the line:

```
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
```

The error dissapears